# Can `rm -rf` reset rooting phone’s system partition?

Tags: root-access, unrooting

As far as I know, a factory reset cannot make the phone unrooted. Then what about system partition?

In rooted Android, apps can have root permission so they can do everything. I want to know if an app performs a factory reset by the command `rm -rf`, will it reset everything including the system partition? Because in a rooted phone, we can change system partitions like controlling the battery and making the click sound disappear when taking photos, etc. I want to know whether factory reset and `rm -rf` can wipe the modified system partition too.

Btw, if I use custom ROM before performing the system partition, will the modified system partition be reset?

Comment: By default the system partition (even of a custom ROM) is read-only, so you would have to remount it writable. With root permissions an app could do so and also delete files and folders on a system partition. But I would not call that "reset", more "eliminate" because if you delete everything on the system partition afterwards there is no os to boot anymore.