# Rooting android phone

Tags: linux

In rooted android , apps can have root permission so they can do everything.
I want to know if an app perform factory reset of command rm-rf,
Will it reset everything including system partition?
Cuz in rooted phone, we can change system partition like controlling battery and making click sound disappear when taking photo etc.

i want to know whether factory resest and rm-rf can wipe modified system partion too.

Comment: The question has already been asked here using a different account: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249264/can-rm-rf-reset-rooting-phone-s-system-partition The other question is better formulated so this one can be closed/deleted.